# C++ Using member functions from a similar virtual public class

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have a bunch of inherited classes like this:

[image: diamond]

...and they all serve the purpose of making all sorts of polynomials. Class `X` is mainly a variable tank, classes `A`, `B`, etc are all `virtual public X` and each creates ont type of polynomial, class `Y` makes the calls. Besides `A` and `B`, any other class can be added.

Now, everything works but for a newly added "virtual public" class I need to reuse some member function(s) from other classes, here from `A` inside class `B`. I tried to make the simplest example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

// variable tank
class X
{
protected:
    // general variables
    double *m_c;
    int m_n;
    double m_w;
    // funcX related
    double m_r;
    int m_i {0};

public:
    ~X() = default;

    /* Simple bracketed root-finding. This is called from more than
     * one "virtual public" classes.
     */
    const double funcX(const double &x, const double &y,    \
                       std::function<const double(const double&, const int&)> fp,   \
                       const int &k)
    {
        double a {x}, b {y}, fmid;
        while (m_i<100)
        {
            m_r = 0.5*(a + b);
            fmid = fp(m_r, k);
            if (fabs(b-a) <= 1e-3)
                break;
            if (fmid < 0)
                b = m_r;
            else
                a = m_r;
            ++m_i;
        }
        return m_r;
    }
};

// one of the many classes that generate polynomials
class A: virtual public X
{
public:

    void funcA(const int &n)
    {
        // set order
        m_n = n;
        // calculate X::m_c[i]
        m_c = new double[m_n+1];
        for (short i=0; i<=m_n>>1; ++i)
        {
            int sgn {i%2 ? -1 : 1};
            m_c[i<<1] = sgn/((i + 1.0)*(i + 1.0));
        }
        // The polynomial is zero somewhere, use funcX() to find where.
        m_w = funcX(5.0, 0.0,   \
                    [this](const double &x, const int &n)   \
                    { return calcA(x, n); },    \
                    m_n);
    }

    // calculates the value of the polynomial of order n, at x
    const double calcA(const double &x, const int &n) const
    {
        double out {static_cast<double>(m_c[0])};
        for (short i=1; i<=n; ++i)
            out = m_c[i] + x*out;
        return out;
    }
};

class B: virtual public X
{
private:
    A m_a;  // otherwise the lambda function does not "catch" it
public:
    void funcB(const int &n)
    {
        // same as in A
        m_n = n;
        // same as in A, calculate coefficients
        m_c = new double[m_n+1];
        for (short i=0; i<=m_n; ++i)
        {
            int sgn {i%2 ? -1 : 1};
            m_c[i] = sgn/((i + 1)<<1);
        }
        /* Here I need A::calcA(). Instead of duplicating the code,
         * I want to call it through X::funcX(). The code compiles,
         * but it crashes.
         */
        m_w = funcX(0.5, 1.0,   \
                    [this](const double &x, const int &n)   \
                    { return m_a.calcA(x, n); },    \
                    m_n);
    }
    const double getW() const { return m_w; }
};

class Y: public A, public B
{
public:
    Y(const int &n, const int &i)
    {
        // call one of the "virtual public" classes through i
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: funcA(n);    break;
        case 2: funcB(n);    break;
        }
    }
    void printC() { for (short i=0; i<=m_n; ++i) std::cout << m_c[i] << '\n'; }
    void printW() { std::cout << m_w << '\n'; }
    void printA(const double &x, const double &n) { std::cout << A::calcA(x, n) << '\n'; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N {6};
    Y *y;
    for (short i=1; i<=2; ++i)
    {
        y = new Y(N, i);
        y->printC();
        y->printW();
        y->printA(1.2, N);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

class `X`:

`X::funcX()` is a simple root-finding algorithm which gets called in more than one `virtual public` classes (`A`, `B`, etc). `m_c`, `m_n`, `m_w` are shared variables.

classes `A` and `B`:

their main function is `funcA()` (and `funcB()`, and so on) and it creates the polynomial (in the body, there's a `for` loop), based on the calculated order, `X::m_n`. Evaluating the polynomial is `A::calcA()`. This needs to be either called by `class B`, too, or redefined. I'd rather avoid the latter because of the code bloating. It also doesn't look very "professional" for my fairly beginner level...

class `Y`

This calls any of the `virtual public` classes based on argument `i` (the `switch/case`).

The code compiles, but crashes. It prints the case for. This example points to `A::funcA()` as the culprit, but in the original program I can see that the coeficients, `m_c[i]`, are not even initialized with dynamic memory, as in trying to print out `m_c[0]` crashes. I tried moving the `new double[]` insode the function in `A`, but that doesn't work.

I don't know how to make it. Does this make sense, is it possible? If yes, how?

---

Edit: Forgot to add that I can't just move `calcA()` from `A` to the top, in `X`, because each polynomial  is evaluated differently, as in there are shortcuts, changes, in every one that makes it possible to have different, optimized evaluations for each polynomial. I could make `X::calcA()` a universal one, but there will be a performance penalty, which I'd rather not pay.

Comment: `y = new Y(N, i);`  -- You are creating a memory leak in your loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see now, I made it `Y y {N, 1}`, then used `y.bla` and now it works. However, in my program I don't even get there. The `m_c[]` array doesn't get initialized. I can't just post everything I have as there are more than 20 files already, and simplifying would mean at the very least 5 of them. Would it help if I showed the errors?

Comment: Please use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers (why you are using everything else except the obvious?).  Once you do that, you see that `m_c` has size 0, but you're accessing it here: `double out{ static_cast<double>(m_c[0]) };`.  [See here](http://ideone.com/TcjUPx)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would have used them but I need to call another root-solving, Jenkins-Traub, which is converted to C++ but has C-style arrays. I tried modifying it, but not only it crashed, but it also took at least double the time to solve. So I just let it be... That `static_cast` is my fault, a left-overfrom when I made the example with `int` coefficients, then I changed to `double` and forgot to remove the cast. My bad.

Comment: The goal is to get the code to work first, and from this, it looks like you were led down the wrong path in determining what may be wrong.  The vector pointed out that you were allocating 0 bytes, and tried to access element 0.  That is what the `std::out_of_range` error is stating and the reason for the crash when I ran the code using your original pointer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your problem is induced by problems with design. When you need to use methods from other class that may mean:

1. The is a problem with "single responsibility" principle. Class does too much. For example numerical equation solving algorithms are self-sufficient entities and shouldn't be part of polynomial. They can work with any polynomial.
2. There is a problem with inheritance tree. For example a common ancestor should be created and that common methods should be in it. Note, that if you can't find short and understandable name for that ancestor, then this is not the solution.
3. Inheritance is not used properly. For example I can't see virtual methods in your code which is strange.

Let's get closer to your example. You are using virtual multiple inheritance which is considered to be very heavy pattern and usually should not be used. Moreover, there are no virtual methods in your code, so you actually do not use inheritance at all. You either must drop inheritance, or think of common methods which make sense for all your classes. For functions this seems to be an ability to calculate function value in specified point. Then move all code, that is not describing polynomials or functions out of the classes. Move out numerical solvers. This will allow to reuse them for all your classes, that support needed interface. Get rid of Y class at all. It seems, that it is needed to emulate virtual methods with switches and enums. You don't need it, rename funcA and funcB just to func if they are semantically the same and do the same thing for different types of polynomials.

Comment: I started with inheritance and I planned to have constructors in classes `A`, `B`, etc called with the `switch/case` inside `Y` (which also handles outputting to screen results, and more), but I couldn't do it, so I switched to simple member functions, like `funcA()`. The classes, themselves, are made simpe, as in they only create the type of polynomial, that's it. Class `X` holds the variables, common to `A`, `B`, etc, and class `Y` prettyfies everything, prints, calculates, evaluates, it's meant to be the "control panel" of the whole thing. Still, you are right, it is messy, and got worse...

Comment: When class Y implements class A that means that Y is a special type of A and can do everything A can. So if Y inherits from A and B, then it is A and B simultaneously. In your example inheritance is used "upside-down". All common functions must be in a base. They may be abstract (specific implementation is provided by ancestors), but they must be defined in the base.

Comment: I tried making it so, the root-finding algorithm is in `X`, at the top, used by anyone that needs it. Suppose it's like this: I need a polynomial printed out and evaluated over a range. `Y` does that, but with which one? `i` is the choice, which calls the appropiate polynomial class, which does only creating the poly. The terms are common to all poly classes, and are stored in `X`. So `Y` calls `A` (if `i=1`), which calculates the poly according to `A`'s rule, using coefficients in `X`. If I need `B`, I call `B`, which is using coeffs from `X`. This would be a brute explanation.

Comment: You should read about virtual methods. That will solve your "which one" problem.

Comment: There was a comment but was deleted shortly after, to use `virtual funcA()` (IIRC), and goes hand in hand with what you're saying. I'll mark this down as the answer and try to restructure everything. I already feel the pain, but hopefully, this will serve as a lesson.